# Using jQuery and nav-list

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I'm using Bootstrap 2.3 and I'm trying to remove the hide class of the `nav-list` if the parent `li` is selected. What I cannot figure out is how to identify the parent `li` of the `nav-list`. For example, when the parent is set to active I would like to see the nested `nav` list to show.

Below is the code example to help explain what I am trying to do:

```
<div class="span3">
    <div class="well sidebar-nav">
        <ul class="nav nav-list">
            <li class="nav-header"><a href="/dealer/home">Main</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav nav-list">
            <li><a href="/dealer/">Parent Page</a></li>
                <ul class="nav nav-list hide">
                    <li><a href="#1">child page 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#2">child page 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#3">child page 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            <li><a href="/dealer2/">Parent Page 2</a></li>
                <ul class="nav nav-list hide">
                    <li><a href="#1">child page 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#2">child page 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#3">child page 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            <li><a href="/dealer3/">Parent Page 3</a></li>
                <ul class="nav nav-list hide">
                    <li><a href="#1">child page 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#2">child page 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#3">child page 3</a></li>
                </ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('nav a[href^="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]').addClass('active');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: When the parent page is "set to active", does it receive a class name as well? Such as .active?

Comment: Yep it does for example <li class=active><a href="/dealer/">Parent Page</a></li>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for using the markup you provided:

```
$('ul.nav li.active').next('ul').removeClass('hide');
```

However, your HTML for your list is not properly formed, you should have something along the lines of(note the change of where the closing `li` for the "parent page" is):

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
    <li><a href="/dealer/">Parent Page</a>
        <ul class="nav nav-list hide">
            <li><a href="#1">child page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#2">child page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#3">child page 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

If you correct the markup to be what is above, then the JS becomes:

```
$('ul.nav li.active').children('ul').removeClass('hide');
```

And a codepen for reference using your provided code:

http://codepen.io/chase_hubbard/pen/jvqKx